# lifecycle callback in laravel 4 eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i am newbie in laravel4. is there a way to set automatically the timestamps() field (created_at, updated_ad) in table ??
may be like Doctrine2 lifecycle callback onUpdate and onDelete event in entity.
thanks before

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Eloquent** then this will already be the case.  It is mentioned in the Laravel documentation under [Database \ Eloquent ORM \ Timestamps](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps).

> ### Timestamps
>
> By default, Eloquent will maintain the created_at and updated_at columns on your database table automatically. Simply add these datetime columns to your table and Eloquent will take care of the rest.